# using case statements in join

Tags: sql

I am trying to do a join on the following two tables:

```
table 1 
id   addr
1    Mumbai
2    delhi
3    Orissa

table 2
flight  add
y       mum
y       del
n       ori
```

my sql query is:

```
select 
b.flight,
a.id
from table2 b
join table1 a 
on b.add = (select case when a.addr = 'Mumbai' then 'mum'
                   when a.addr = 'Delhi' then 'del
                   end);
```

While running this on Netezza, I am getting the following error:

```
This form of correlated query is not supported - consider rewriting
```

Can someone tell me the right approach to do this.

Comment: What DBMS are you using ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`case` is an expression, just like any other expression. You don't need a correlated query there, you can just use the expression directly:

```
select 
b.flight,
a.id
from table2 b
join table1 a 
on b.add = case when a.addr = 'Mumbai' then 'mum'
                when a.addr = 'Delhi' then 'del
           end;
```

Comment: You are not pointing him on the right way. He may want a substring of 3 characters

Comment: did answer the question though, so +1

Comment: @Cid: It doesn't look so. In the original query they are only trying to join Mumbai and Delhi, not Orissa. I think this answer is good, because it shows the OP that they were thinking too complicatedly

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I got your point and didn't noticed Orissa was missing. OP may have forgot that or it is intentional.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SUBSTRING` and `LOWER` for your requirement

```
select 
b.flight,
a.id
from table2 b
join table1 a 
on b.add = SUBSTRING(LOWER(a.addr), 1, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell if Netezza supports or not that kind of join, but you can move the case statement in a subquery like this:

```
select 
  b.flight,
  a.id
from table2 b join (
  select id, 
    case addr 
      when 'Mumbai' then 'mum'
      when 'Delhi' then 'del'
    end addr
  from table1 
) a on b.add = a.addr;
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to write this join if you're looking for the `addr` in table 1 that begins with the value `add` in table 2 would be to use Like

```
select  b.flight
        , a.id
from    table1 as a
join    table2 as b on a.addr like b.[add] + '%'
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4eb1c/5)

Comment: Thank you for the answers guys. Its working fine now

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to join 'Mumbai' with 'mum' and 'delhi'  with 'del', then you can simply check the pairings:

```
select b.flight, a.id
from table2 b
join table1 a on (b.add = 'mum' and a.addr = 'Mumbai')
              or (b.add = 'del' and a.addr = 'delhi')
```

As you see, you don't need `CASE WHEN` in `WHERE` and `ON` conditions, as you can simply use `AND` and `OR`.

I don't know Netezza. Maybe it even supports tuples:

```
select b.flight, a.id
from table2 b
join table1 a on (b.add, a.addr) in (('mum', 'Mumbai'), ('del', 'delhi'))
```